# jQuery / Javascript count how many times a key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

Is there any way to count how many times [a-z][0-9] keys are pressed from user?

I would like to count how many time he press the keys on an input text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `onKeyPress:{if(event.key is [a-z0-9]) counter++}`. Of course, you have to fill in some blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code would maintain a map giving for each key the number of key press :

```
var map = {};
$('input')​​​​.keyup(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (key>=48 && key<=90) map[key] = (map[key]||0)+1;
});​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/LZVJQ/) (open the console)

You can find [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) the relation between the key codes and the chars.

If you want to have a map more readable (with characters as keys instead of key codes), do this :

```
var map = {};
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode>=48 && e.keyCode<=90) {
      var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
      map[key] = (map[key]||0)+1;
    }
});​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/7Vnup/) (open the console)

But it would probably be easier to just analyze the string (obtained using `val`) at end of entry.

Answer (score 2):

This code works, replace `#yourinputid` with your input's id and the `keycode == '13'` with the key you want to count, 13 is actually `Enter`. Just look at `nbr`'s value and you'll know how many time the key was pressed.

```
var nbr = 0;
    $('#yourinputid').keypress(
       function(event)
       {     
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
            nbr++;  
       }
    });
```

Good luck.

You can add multiple keycode if you change the condition with `OR` statements.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/D2EBA/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('#txt').keypress(function(event){
        var key_code = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if((key_code  >=97 && key_code  <=122) || (key_code  >=48 && key_code <=57)){
           $('#cnt').html(++count);
        }     
    });
});​
```